# S.M.A.R.T pending and offline sectors warning

Tags: external-hard-drive, smart, bad-sectors

Here are information on  my 8 month armor a 65 external hard drive by HD tune

```
HD Tune Pro: PHD 3.0 Silicon-Power Health

ID                               Current  Worst    ThresholdData             Status   
(01) Raw Read Error Rate         79       57       6        74624347         ok       
(03) Spin Up Time                97       97       0        0                ok       
(04) Start/Stop Count            98       98       20       2713             ok       
(05) Reallocated Sector Count    100      100      36       0                ok       
(07) Seek Error Rate             81       60       45       118160959        ok       
(09) Power On Hours Count        96       96       0        103663330660337  ok       
(0A) Spin Retry Count            100      100      97       0                ok       
(0C) Power Cycle Count           100      100      20       388              ok       
(B8) End To End Error Detection  100      100      99       0                ok       
(BB) Uncorrectable Error Count   1        1        0        383              ok       
(BC) Command Timeout             100      93       0        343602626718     ok       
(BD) Unknown Attribute           100      100      0        0                ok       
(BE) Airflow Temperature         76       46       40       404029464        ok       
(BF) G-sense Error Rate          100      100      0        0                ok       
(C0) Unsafe Shutdown Count       100      100      0        31               ok       
(C1) Load Cycle Count            70       70       0        61040            ok       
(C2) Temperature                 24       54       0        77309411352      ok       
(C5) Current Pending Sector      88       88       0        1024             warning  
(C6) Offline Uncorrectable       88       88       0        1024             ok       
(C7) Interface CRC Error Count   200      200      0        0                ok       
(F0) Head Flying Hours           100      253      0        253987186018269  ok       
(F1) Unknown Attribute           100      253      0        17337761034      ok       
(F2) Unknown Attribute           100      253      0        16339573368      ok       
(FE) Unknown Attribute           100      100      0        0                ok       

Health Status         : warning
```

and here are info based on CrystalDisckInfo

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CrystalDiskInfo 7.5.0 (C) 2008-2017 hiyohiyo
                                Crystal Dew World : https://crystalmark.info/
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    OS : Windows 8.1 Pro [6.3 Build 9600] (x64)
  Date : 2017/11/28 15:38:04

-- Controller Map ----------------------------------------------------------
 + Intel(R) 8 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller [ATA]
   - ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB
   - HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GUA0N
 - Microsoft Storage Spaces Controller [SCSI]

-- Disk List ---------------------------------------------------------------
 (1) ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB : 1000.2 GB [0/0/0, pd1] - st
 (2) ST2000LM007-1R8174 : 2000.3 GB [1/0/0, sa1] - st

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 (1) ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
           Model : ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB
        Firmware : 2BA30001
   Serial Number : S30YJ9AF414622
       Disk Size : 1000.2 GB (7.9/137.4/1000.2/1000.2)
     Buffer Size : 16384 KB
     Queue Depth : 32
    # of Sectors : 1953525168
   Rotation Rate : 5400 RPM
       Interface : Serial ATA
   Major Version : ATA8-ACS
   Minor Version : ATA8-ACS version 6
   Transfer Mode : SATA/600 | SATA/600
  Power On Hours : 5558 hours
  Power On Count : 2140 count
     Temperature : 33 C (91 F)
   Health Status : Good
        Features : S.M.A.R.T., APM, AAM, 48bit LBA, NCQ
       APM Level : 0080h [ON]
       AAM Level : FE00h [OFF]
    Drive Letter : C: D: E: G:

-- S.M.A.R.T. --------------------------------------------------------------
ID Cur Wor Thr RawValues(6) Attribute Name
01 100 100 _51 000000000000 Read Error Rate
02 252 252 __0 000000000000 Throughput Performance
03 _92 _81 _25 000000000988 Spin-Up Time
04 _98 _98 __0 000000000B84 Start/Stop Count
05 252 252 _10 000000000000 Reallocated Sectors Count
07 252 252 _51 000000000000 Seek Error Rate
08 252 252 _15 000000000000 Seek Time Performance
09 100 100 __0 0000000015B6 Power-On Hours
0A 252 252 _51 000000000000 Spin Retry Count
0B 100 100 __0 000000000092 Recalibration Retries
0C _98 _98 __0 00000000085C Power Cycle Count
BF 100 100 __0 000000000095 G-Sense Error Rate
C0 252 252 __0 000000000000 Power-off Retract Count
C2 _64 _53 __0 002F00140021 Temperature
C3 100 100 __0 000000000000 Hardware ECC recovered
C4 252 252 __0 000000000000 Reallocation Event Count
C5 252 252 __0 000000000000 Current Pending Sector Count
C6 252 252 __0 000000000000 Uncorrectable Sector Count
C7 200 200 __0 000000000000 UltraDMA CRC Error Count
C8 100 100 __0 00000000035D Write Error Rate
DF 100 100 __0 000000000092 Load/Unload Retry Count
E1 _82 _82 __0 00000002C88B Load/Unload Cycle Count

-- SMART_READ_DATA ---------------------------------------------------------
     +0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 +8 +9 +A +B +C +D +E +F
000: 10 00 01 2F 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 26
010: 00 FC FC 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 23 00 5C 51 88
020: 09 00 00 00 00 00 04 32 00 62 62 84 0B 00 00 00
030: 00 00 05 33 00 FC FC 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 2E
040: 00 FC FC 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 24 00 FC FC 00
050: 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 32 00 64 64 B6 15 00 00 00
060: 00 00 0A 32 00 FC FC 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0B 32
070: 00 64 64 92 00 00 00 00 00 00 0C 32 00 62 62 5C
080: 08 00 00 00 00 00 BF 22 00 64 64 95 00 00 00 00
090: 00 00 C0 22 00 FC FC 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C2 02
0A0: 00 40 35 21 00 14 00 2F 00 00 C3 3A 00 64 64 00
0B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 C4 32 00 FC FC 00 00 00 00 00
0C0: 00 00 C5 32 00 FC FC 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C6 30
0D0: 00 FC FC 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C7 36 00 C8 C8 00
0E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 C8 2A 00 64 64 5D 03 00 00 00
0F0: 00 00 DF 32 00 64 64 92 00 00 00 00 00 00 E1 32
100: 00 52 52 8B C8 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
110: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
120: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
130: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
140: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
150: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
160: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 B0 31 00 5B
170: 03 00 01 00 02 D4 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
180: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
190: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1C0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F2

-- SMART_READ_THRESHOLD ----------------------------------------------------
     +0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 +8 +9 +A +B +C +D +E +F
000: 10 00 01 33 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 19 00 00 00 00
020: 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
030: 00 00 05 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 33
040: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 0F 00 00 00 00
050: 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
060: 00 00 0A 33 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0B 00
070: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0C 00 00 00 00 00
080: 00 00 00 00 00 00 BF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
090: 00 00 C0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C2 00
0A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C3 00 00 00 00 00
0B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 C4 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0C0: 00 00 C5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C6 00
0D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C7 00 00 00 00 00
0E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 C8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0F0: 00 00 DF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 E1 00
100: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
110: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
120: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
130: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
140: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
150: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
160: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
170: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
180: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
190: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1C0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3B

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 (2) ST2000LM007-1R8174
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Enclosure : PHD 3.0 Silicon-Power USB Device (V=13FD, P=3940, sa1) - st
           Model : ST2000LM007-1R8174
        Firmware : SBK2
   Serial Number : WCC1N05D
       Disk Size : 2000.3 GB (8.4/137.4/2000.3/2000.3)
     Buffer Size : Unknown
     Queue Depth : 32
    # of Sectors : 3907029168
   Rotation Rate : 5400 RPM
       Interface : USB (Serial ATA)
   Major Version : ACS-3
   Minor Version : ACS-3 Revision 3b
   Transfer Mode : SATA/300 | SATA/600
  Power On Hours : 4081 hours
  Power On Count : 388 count
     Temperature : 26 C (78 F)
   Health Status : Caution
        Features : S.M.A.R.T., APM, 48bit LBA, NCQ
       APM Level : 8080h [ON]
       AAM Level : ----
    Drive Letter : K:

-- S.M.A.R.T. --------------------------------------------------------------
ID Cur Wor Thr RawValues(6) Attribute Name
01 _79 _57 __6 00000472AD5B Read Error Rate
03 _97 _97 __0 000000000000 Spin-Up Time
04 _98 _98 _20 000000000A9A Start/Stop Count
05 100 100 _36 000000000000 Reallocated Sectors Count
07 _81 _60 _45 0000070AFE41 Seek Error Rate
09 _96 _96 __0 1E8D00000FF1 Power-On Hours
0A 100 100 _97 000000000000 Spin Retry Count
0C 100 100 _20 000000000184 Power Cycle Count
B8 100 100 _99 000000000000 End-to-End Error
BB __1 __1 __0 00000000017F Reported Uncorrectable Errors
BC 100 _93 __0 00500050009E Command Timeout
BD 100 100 __0 000000000000 High Fly Writes
BE _74 _46 _40 00001A15001A Airflow Temperature
BF 100 100 __0 000000000000 G-Sense Error Rate
C0 100 100 __0 00000000001F Power-off Retract Count
C1 _70 _70 __0 00000000EE72 Load/Unload Cycle Count
C2 _26 _54 __0 00120000001A Temperature
C5 _88 _88 __0 000000000400 Current Pending Sector Count
C6 _88 _88 __0 000000000400 Uncorrectable Sector Count
C7 200 200 __0 000000000000 UltraDMA CRC Error Count
F0 100 253 __0 2965000007DD Head Flying Hours
F1 100 253 __0 000409693D0A Total Host Writes
F2 100 253 __0 0004CDEA1A78 Total Host Reads
FE 100 100 __0 000000000000 Free Fall Protection

-- SMART_READ_DATA ---------------------------------------------------------
     +0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 +8 +9 +A +B +C +D +E +F
000: 0A 00 01 0F 00 4F 39 5B AD 72 04 00 00 00 03 03
010: 00 61 61 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 32 00 62 62 9A
020: 0A 00 00 00 00 00 05 33 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00
030: 00 00 07 0F 00 51 3C 41 FE 0A 07 00 00 00 09 32
040: 00 60 60 F1 0F 00 00 8D 1E 22 0A 13 00 64 64 00
050: 00 00 00 00 00 00 0C 32 00 64 64 84 01 00 00 00
060: 00 00 B8 32 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 BB 32
070: 00 01 01 7F 01 00 00 00 00 00 BC 32 00 64 5D 9E
080: 00 50 00 50 00 00 BD 3A 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00
090: 00 00 BE 22 00 4A 2E 1A 00 15 1A 00 00 00 BF 32
0A0: 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C0 32 00 64 64 1F
0B0: 00 00 00 00 00 01 C1 32 00 46 46 72 EE 00 00 00
0C0: 00 00 C2 22 00 1A 36 1A 00 00 00 12 00 00 C5 12
0D0: 00 58 58 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 C6 10 00 58 58 00
0E0: 04 00 00 00 00 00 C7 3E 00 C8 C8 00 00 00 00 00
0F0: 00 00 F0 00 00 64 FD DD 07 00 00 65 29 09 F1 00
100: 00 64 FD 0A 3D 69 09 04 00 00 F2 00 00 64 FD 78
110: 1A EA CD 04 00 00 FE 32 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00
120: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
130: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
140: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
150: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
160: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 73
170: 03 00 01 00 01 FF 02 55 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
180: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 03 03 03 03 03
190: 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00
1A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 79 2D 19 66 5D 0D 00 00
1B0: 00 00 00 00 01 00 5E 01 0A 3D 69 09 04 00 00 00
1C0: 78 1A EA CD 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 2A 1E 00 00 03 00 00 00
1E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10
1F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 18 00 00 00 9B

-- SMART_READ_THRESHOLD ----------------------------------------------------
     +0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 +8 +9 +A +B +C +D +E +F
000: 01 00 01 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00
010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 14 00 00 00 00
020: 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
030: 00 00 07 2D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 00
040: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0A 61 00 00 00 00
050: 00 00 00 00 00 00 0C 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
060: 00 00 B8 63 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 BB 00
070: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 BC 00 00 00 00 00
080: 00 00 00 00 00 00 BD 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
090: 00 00 BE 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 BF 00
0A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C0 00 00 00 00 00
0B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 C1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0C0: 00 00 C2 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C5 00
0D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C6 00 00 00 00 00
0E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 C7 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0F0: 00 00 F0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F1 00
100: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F2 00 00 00 00 00
110: 00 00 00 00 00 00 FE 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
120: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
130: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
140: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
150: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
160: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
170: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
180: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
190: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1C0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 92
```

I contacted SP customer service via email and they said the hard drive needs to be replaced. But because I live in Iran and  warranty here is a mess I do not think they are gonna replace it or even accept there is anything wrong with this hard drive. I am going to buy a new hard drive today and backup all my data.

I want advice about what to do with this hard after I backed up my data. Can I do anything in order to repair it myself? Will a long format and surface test help? How bad is health situation? Should I ever use this hard drive again?

also about testing this  with its own tool , SP toolbox fails to reorganize drive , i tested this on another laptop and still toolbox wont even find it.

Comment: I would zero the drive and test again... For some reason a bad sector(s) hasn't been remapped by the drive's firmware yet (low level, not filesystem based) and it's pending, if it doesn't increment it might just need a low level format, if it increments it's likely a bad disk. I would definitely not trust this drive, immediately make a backup of all important data and seek a replacement as soon as possible. Your likelyhood of data loss increases with every minute the disk is used.

Comment: Why the profanity?

Answer (score 0):

The drive is on its way out and you would be riskky to do anything with it other then attempt to RMA it or throw it away after copying the data off it and overwriting it.

Hard drives do not have user serviceable parts as the tolerances require very specialised equipment.

Because I am bloody minded I would back up my data, then push the drive very hard (lots of writes) and try to make it fail do Seagate will honor their obligations.  I might also be inclined to ensure it's pushed to it's limits in other ways to encourage it's failure. (Are you sure the drive will perform to it's drop rating, and near the minimum and maximum temperatures it's rated at - being mindful of humidity). Worst case Is I document the process and post on YouTube.

Comment: thanks. i am copying data right now and will attempt to RMA it , but i am not really optimistic that they are going to replace it. sorry if it sound noob but what do you mean by "do Seagate will honor their obligations" are you talking a bout my internal hard drive or making example of Seagate ?

Comment: I expect that if the drive status changes from Caution to Failed, Seagate will RMA the drive. I'm not talking about making an example of them.  I'm not sure if you are aware they offer an online process for RMA'ing faulty drives (in case you are worried about the retailer denying your claim - but I am guessing SP implies Seagate Products?)

Comment: If you document stress testing a drive on YouTube, people may be interested in seeing how far it can be pushed before it breaks.  I was not suggesting Seagate will care.